Did more than two prostrations in sujud as sahw. Is my prayer valid?
I made two mistakes in my Salah and I thought I needed to offer four prostrations meaning sujud as sahw twice. I realized my mistake afterwards is my prayer valid or not?

This answer is only with regards to the Hanafi school of thought and may be different in others.
In doing an extra sajdah (or 2 in your case) you have not missed out a waajib act but have delayed a fardh act. This entails for you to do sajdah sahwah. However, as you have already reached the last sitting, it is recommended for you to repeat your salaah.
As the time for the salaah you were praying has concluded, your salaah will count

Your prayer is not invalid as you did all basic things(fard) right, ALLAH is great to forgive minor mistakes.However, I suggest you to check out this link to learn more about possible cases and the applicability of sujud as sahw.
